# C++, How to use const Objects and non-const Objects in comparison?

Tags: c++

I overloaded the operator== to compare two objects of the same class and it works perfectly.

But if want to use the comparison for const objects I can not compile.

I know that I can just write an additional operator== with a const parameter, but is there a way to use the same method for const and non-const objects?

Comment: Just write a single `operator==` where both operands are `const` references. A `const` reference can refer to a non-`const` instance.

Answer (score 4):

If your overload takes the objects by `const` reference, then a non-const object will bind automatically to it.

In other words, there's no need to provide a non-`const` version.

Comment: Arguably, it's incorrect to provide a non-`const` version, because `operator==` should never modify its operands.